# TypeError: Cannot read property 'humidity' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to make an API call, then hydrate the page in data i receive, however I can't figure out how to conditionally render what's on the page. As soon as the page loads i get the error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'humidity' of undefined". I want to be able to show the same view with empty spaces until the user interacts with the page.

Here is my code

```
const handleInputChange = (e) => {
  setSearch(e.target.value)
};

const handleCall = () => {
  API.getWeather(search)
    .then(res => {
      setWeather(res.data)
    })
};

return (
<h2> Feels Like: {weather.main.temp}</h2>

<ul>
<li>Humidity: {weather.main.humidity}</li>
<li>Max Temp: {weather.main.temp_max}</li>
</ul>
)
```

Comment: What is the initial state value for `weather`? Can you update to include complete component code? You likely need to use conditional rendering or some other form of guarding "access of undefined" errors like access checks or optional chaining.

Comment: Sorry, I should've added that. The initial state for weather is just an empty array. I couldn't figure out the conditional rendering, so i tried using useEffect() to let it have data from the first load but it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

Use of guard pattern

```
return (
  <h2> Feels Like: {weather && weather.main && weather.main.temp}</h2>

  <ul>
    <li>Humidity: {weather && weather.main && weather.main.humidity}</li>
    <li>Max Temp: {weather && weather.main && weather.main.temp_max}</li>
  </ul>
)
```

Use of optional chaining

```
return (
  <h2> Feels Like: {weather?.main?.temp}</h2>

  <ul>
    <li>Humidity: {weather?.main?.humidity}</li>
    <li>Max Temp: {weather?.main?.temp_max}</li>
  </ul>
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like

```
weather && weather.main && weather.main.temp || "Loading..."
```

This way, until you have the data in your system, the word "Loading..." will appear